# ASP.Net MaxPoolSize configuration issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, connection-pooling

I don't know much about .Net Application Scalability and I'm sure some SO users know more about it and could help me out.

I know some questions have already been asked in the past, about having Connection Pool Overflows. Most of the time, it ends up talking about "How to close your connections properly" (which I highly think it's not my case, since all of my LinqToSQL queries are `Disposed` accordingly, using this kind of code):

```
using (MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext())
{
    return (from o in context.t_Orders
            where o.order_id.Equals(_id)
            select o).ToList();
}
```

Also, most of the answers I've read end up saying "A website should not require many concurrent connections, even for hundreds of users". But I'm talking about a massive WebApp, having over 500 concurrent users (who might be logging in in the same 2 minute range). Also, every page access is logged in a table (so consider multiple reads and inserts).

Now, I wonder if the default `MaxPoolSize` of 100 connections is enough or could be a risk? If it might represent any risk, how should I modify the Connection Pooling settings?
Should I increase the `MaxPoolSize` to a certain % of the concurrent users. Would it have any negative effect? Or should I increase the `ConnectionTimeout` in order to prevent any `InvalidOperationException`?

By the way, I entirely red William Vaughn's article "[The .NET Connection Pool Lifeguard -
Prevent pool overflows that can drown your applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175863%28SQL.80%29.aspx)", but I'm still pretty worried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concurrent users doesn't mean anything. Concurrent requests is more meaningful. Will you have more than 100 requests in-flight at the same time? In that case I'd definitely increase max pool size because increasing the setting has no cost by itself.

You can safely increase it to at least 250. If you want to do more, you need to test (or redesign the application).

Comment: So I guess "safely increase it to at least 250" means that SQL Server 2012 can handle that many connections from the Web Server?

Comment: Oh it can handle tens of thousands. I just wouldn't want to open more than 250 connections without knowing about it as this is likely to be an application design flaw. Also, you might have multiple clients opening 250 connections each. Next, I have used the 250 setting personally but not more. So I cannot vouch for it to work (I have tested the maximum, though, which was 30k for my dev box).

Comment: The actual situation is that 550 students are going to access the application at the almost same moment, since the application let them complete an online exam at a very specific moment. I guess it'll be safer to increase the MaxPoolSize to 250 connections, just in case. Thanks again usr.

Comment: Ok. Remember, that each student will use the application only for milliseconds, though (maybe 100? depends on your app). I repeat: #Users >> #DB-Connections.

Comment: I know requests to my DB only take 10 milliseconds, but in the case the exam is available at 10'o'clock and they're all going to hit "Start" at the same moment, do you think there might be a risk that (maybe) more than 100 connections are used at that time?

Comment: At 10ms a pop and 100 concurrent connections you can service 100k requests per second... I'd not worry about it. Note, that establishing a connection might be much more expensive than 10ms! You might actually *increase* latency.

Comment: 100 concurrent connections can service 10k requests per second, but you are right, I must not consider only the query execution time. Anyhow, thanks for your knowledge, it'll certainly help me configure my app settings and let me a little less worried!